# Creating meta cells from scRNA-seq and scATAC-seq for GRN analysis

Tags: scrnaseq, atac-seq

We have two 10X Genomics scRNA-seq and scATAC-seq datasets generated from similar cells, but in different experiments - separately, not using the multiome platform. Now, we are trying to use Pando (https://github.com/quadbiolab/Pando) to generate a gene regulatory network.

We have successfully converted our CCA-embedded dataset into h5ad format (https://mojaveazure.github.io/seurat-disk/articles/convert-anndata.html), then used bipartite matching (https://github.com/quadbiolab/organoid_regulomes) to receive a .tsv file matching invidiual cells from both datasets - it gives us the barcodes of the cells in both the scRNA and scATAC datasets. Now, we need to actually generate metacells/pseudocells that contain both modalities inside the same cell to be able to use Pando.

According to Fleck et al. 2022 (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-05279-8), they state

> The metacells were integrated using cluster similarity spectrum (CSS)

which would refer to this technique: https://github.com/quadbiolab/simspec/blob/master/vignette/vignette.md
However, that does not make use of the previously generated bipartite-matched cell list.

I'm a little bit lost here - can someone point me in the right direction to how we can generate the metacells containing both modalities, scRNA and scATAC?

Thanks a lot in advance!